# Combining two mod_rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I suck at rewrite rules so.. pity me >_>

I want to get these two rules to work together.. basically I want to remove the www whenever its used, then send all requests to index.php with a GET variable if theres stuff after the domain..

Eg: www.example.com and www.example.com/foo would go to example.com and example.com/foo respectively.

Heres what I have to merge:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
    RewriteRule     (.*) index.php?token=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I havent tested this so I donno.. but I highly doubt I have it right.

**EDIT**: Just to clarify, I dont mean to say that need to be one rule, but will they work together as expected?

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't that work just fine? Why does it need to be 1 rule?

Comment: No need to merge.  The 301 will happen if the condition doesn't fail, and then it will be skipped and the second rule will kick in.

Comment: And if I wanted to wildcard the domains? There will be multiple domains pointed at this server and I want domain the user typed in clicked to be preserved for stats, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be OK because your first rule is marked [L] Last and [R] Redirect - so both rules won't have to process at the same time.  The first one will process, redirect, clear the first, then the second one processes.

You could use [C] to Chain together the conditions - meaning that if the first one passes, the next one is tried, but if the first one fails then all Chained subsequents are skipped.  I don't think that's what you want here.  If anything, you'd want an [OR] directive.

Your rewrite looks decent, except for possibly that last one, which – if you're using this for a CodeIgniter site – **usually** look like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

As a best-practice, you should setup a duplicate site at a test-subdomain.example.com so that you can fiddle with things like this in as close to a live environment as possible.

to your comment: if you want to wildcard the domains, just:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.[^.]+\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[^.]+.([^.]+).com/(.*)$ http://$1.com/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is it possible to wildcard the domains?

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but if I wanted the TLD to be wildcard aswell would it just be something like ^www\.[^.]+\.[^.]$ and ^[^.]+.([^.]+).[^.]/(.*)$ http://$1.$2/$3 .. or do I have that wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a complex website can have hundreds of rules in the `.htaccess` file, each with their own set of `RewriteCond`.  There is no need to merge them into some all-encompassing-rule.